# Override the WordPress default pagination markup

Tags: pagination, navigation

I want to render the WordPress posts pagination markup with my own HTML markup. My theme has a pagination markup with `ul > li` format. But the WordPress default pagination markup is different than my markup.

How can I apply my own HTML markup instead of the default pagination markup?

Comment: Depends on what you use to print the pagination. Show us the code.

Answer (score 0):

do you mean post archive pagination? The `paginate_links()` function accepts a `type` parameter, so if all you need is a `ul > li` format you could try out something like:

```
    // archive pagination
    global $wp_query;
    $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

    echo paginate_links( [
        'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
        `type`  => 'list',
    ] );
```

If you need a completely custom markup, you could try setting `type` param to `'array'` and then build whatever you need with a `foreach` loop.

docs: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/paginate_links/